# in this example, I need the last statement to be, if the DRS is 3.1.05, not to show a date or just show 0

Tags: sharepoint, formula

```
=IF(DRS="1.1.01", DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date) + 3, MONTH([Cut Off Date]), DAY([Cut Off Date])),
 IF(DRS="1.4.15", DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date]) + 7, MONTH([Cut Off Date]), DAY([Cut Off Date])),
 IF(DRS="3.1.05", DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date]) + 15, MONTH([Cut Off Date]), DAY([Cut Off Date])),
 [Cut Off Date])))
```

I've tried taking that part out, it didn't work; I've tried *0, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you describe in detail the columns you are dealing with and the type of columns? Also, I don't quite understand your logic for this formula, can you please describe it in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Try using either of below formulas for your SharePoint list calculated column:

```
=IF(DRS="1.1.01", DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date) + 3, MONTH([Cut Off Date]), DAY([Cut Off Date])),
 IF(DRS="1.4.15", DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date]) + 7, MONTH([Cut Off Date]), DAY([Cut Off Date])),""))
```

**OR**

```
=IF(DRS="1.1.01", DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date) + 3, MONTH([Cut Off Date]), DAY([Cut Off Date])),
 IF(DRS="1.4.15", DATE(YEAR([Cut Off Date]) + 7, MONTH([Cut Off Date]), DAY([Cut Off Date])),
 IF(DRS="3.1.05", "","")))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

Comment: It worked!!!  Thanks so much.

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked for you!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept this as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.